# Problem Opening SQLite Connection in VB.net

Tags: database, vb.net, sqlite

I am trying to learn SQLLite (Years of Experience with apps using SQL Server).  I am going slowly and right off the bat I could not open a connection to a database created in SQLite Studio. I have tried a number of different examples with no luck.  I first tried with a Nuget package and then went to the SQLite website and downloaded the 64-bit binaries for .Net 4.5. I get this error no matter what I try:  system.BadImageFormatException.

Can someone please tell me what I'm doing wrong or point me to an example that really works?

Thanks!!!

```
Imports System.Data.SQLite

Public Class Form1

    Private connectionstring As String

    Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

        Dim exePath As String = System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(Application.ExecutablePath)
        Dim dbPath As String = exePath & "\NamesTest.db"

        connectionstring = "Data Source=" & dbPath

    End Sub

    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click


        Dim SQLiteConn As New SQLiteConnection(connectionstring)
        SQLiteConn.Open()
    End Sub

End Class
```

Comment: Usually _BadImageFormatException_ is caused by incompatible bitness of your application  against the bitness of the library. If you have the 64bit version of SQLite then your application should match with AnyCPU or x64.

Comment: have you tested one of these https://www.connectionstrings.com/sqlite/

Comment: It's a bit silly using `Path.GetDirectoryName(Application.ExecutablePath)` when you can use `Application.StartupPath`. Also, you should be using the `Path` class to combine partial paths: `Dim dbPath = Path.Combine(Application.StartupPath, "NamesTest.db")`.

Comment: In addition to what @Steve said, if you are compiling with "AnyCPU", make sure that the "Prefer 32 bit" flag is off in the project properties page.

Comment: Thanks everyone.  Turning off "Prefer 32 bit stopped the error message and opened the database.  I did a simple select query to get all rows from my one table and read them with a data reader.  I agree my way to get the database path was "silly."  I'm going to chang the code as suggessted so I won't be silly :) PROBLEM SOLVED!!!!